# Get unread count for already authorized Google account / Google analytics API

Tags: javascript, gmail, google-apps-script

I have a dashboard with different datas coming from google analytics api. Everything works fine. Now I want to get a counter for all unread mails regarding the same account, which is already authorized. How can I do this? I would prefer to do this in javascript.
Thank you

Comment: Do any of the posts answer your question? If so please use the "tick" option to mark that response as the answer. If not, you can edit your question and clarify it so people have an opportunity to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

To count unread mail in a Gmail mailbox you can use [Gmail Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail) in Google Apps Script, specifically [GmailThread#isUnread](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailthread#isUnread).

Here is an example:

```
// Count unread threads of your inbox
var unreadCount = 0;
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  if (threads[i].isUnread()) {
      unreadCount++;
  }
  Logger.log('Unread? ' + threads[i].isUnread()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following (your ? or not...) comment/answer, Peter's code is working fine and even finer when moving the log in the condition like this (easier to read ;-)

```
function test(){
var unreadCount = 0;
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  if (threads[i].isUnread()) {
      unreadCount++;
  Logger.log('Unread? ' + threads[i].isUnread()+' - '+threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()); 
  }
}
Logger.log('unreadCount = '+unreadCount)
}
```